# How to put line breaks on strings Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, nsstring

If I have a string in Objective-C called text that is a really long, such as:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _sometext];
```

How can I scan `_sometext` and add a line break to the string every hundred characters (letters)?

So if I had the `_sometext` as

> It was November. Although it was not yet late, the sky was dark when I
>   turned into Laundress Passage. Father had finished for the day,
>   switched off the shop lights and closed the shutters; but so I would
>   not come home to darkness he had left on the light over the stairs to
>   the flat.

How can I make it so it puts a line break after

> It was November. Although it was not yet late, the sky was dark when I
>   turned into Laundress Passage

and after

> . Father had finished for the day, switched off the shop lights and
>   closed the shutters; but so I wo

(since those were 100 characters)?

But instead of stopping in the middle of the word, I could it would skip the word and end at the previous word. Example: if the sentence ended at "*but so I wo*" and it cut of the word "would", it would stop at this instead of "*but so I*".

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I can think of off the top of my head is a two step process.

Step one involves breaking the original string into an array of 100 character strings.

Step two involves joining that array of strings with the newline character.

```
NSMutableArray *lines = [NSMutableArray array];

while ([originalString length] > 100) {
    [lines addObject:[originalString substringToIndex:100]];
    originalString = [originalString substringFromIndex:100];
}
[lines addObject: originalString];

NSString *reformattedString = [lines componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Comment: these lines `[lines addObject:[_text subStringToIndex:100]];` and `_text = [_text subStringFromIndex:100];` bring me errors for some reason

Comment: no visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'subStringFromIndex' and 'subStringToIndex'

Comment: Try `substring` in both cases.  Make the second s lowercase.

Comment: this worked! also do you know how to make it not cut off in the middle of the word? right now, it splits after 100 characters exactly

Answer (score 1):

You could write code that would use the method `rangeOfString:options:range:`
 to do that.

You'd create an `NSRange` for the first 100 characters of your string. Then you'd search backwards in that range for a space. When you found a space, you'd add from the beginning of the string to the space to your output string, plus a line break. Then you'd set your search range to the next 100 characters of your string after the space, and again search backwards for a space. Repeat until you've processed the entire string.

See the NSString class reference for the details on the `rangeOfString:options:range:` method.